# Add Multiple UIImageViews to a subclassed UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, subview

I have created a file which subclasses UIView.
I have declared two other imageViews called background and character respectively.

I want them layered in this order: self->background->character.

Here's what it looks like currently:

[Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2baaj.png)

The red border is the UIView, the green is the background, and the character is in blue (it's already in place which is why you can't see it). I want to move the background+character to the UIView's position.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
    self.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 600.0f, 600.0f);
    [self addSubview:self.background];
    self.background.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 60.0f, 60.0f);

    [self.background addSubview:self.character];
    self.character.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 60.0f, 60.0f);

    self.character.center = [self.background convertPoint:self.background.center toView:self.character];
```

I don't know why I have to set self.bounds to 600.0f but that's what makes it the correct size. Any help would be appreaciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar layout issues in the past. The way I was able to get things to line up (if you're not using auto layout) is to use negative x and y coordinates view in front.